# Access to WeakMap items

Tags: javascript

Why is there no direct access to items in WeakMap? And when the garbage collector deletes the link that is the key to WeakMap then also the value that was tied to this key is deleted?

Comment: What do you mean by "no direct access" to the items? You can just use the `get()` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap#Methods

Answer (score 2):

By "direct access to items", I assume you mean why they are not enumerable? Here's the MDN explanation:

> Because of references being weak, WeakMap keys are not enumerable (i.e. there is no method giving you a list of the keys). If they were, the list would depend on the state of garbage collection, introducing non-determinism. If you want to have a list of keys, you should use a `Map`.

I am not sure I understand the second part of the question. An entry (i.e. key-value pair) is eligible to be deleted from the `WeakMap` if there are no non-weak references to the key. What happens to the value would be the same as what happens if it were deleted from `Map`, or from anywhere else: if it was the last non-weak reference to that value, it becomes eligible for garbage collection. However, as long as the entry (the key-value pair) is surviving in a `WeakMap`, the value is considered to be referenced, and will not be garbage-collected.

Answer (score 0):

The `WeakMap`'s intended functionality is to allow items added to it to be automatically garbage-collected if the WeakMap itself would be the only remaining holder of that item. This is useful to keep a reference to some object while another object exists (the usual use case for this is to implement class-private properties/access) and also provides security previously not possible in JavaScript - you can only access the value if you have the "key".

Due to the nature of WeakMaps, its properties cannot be directly iterated through - an item can only be accessed if you have the item's key. If either the key no longer exists (an old object) or if the key is not accessible from that part of the code then you have no way of accessing the value.

If you need to access the values from elsewhere or iterate through all the values, you should use `Map`. However, a Map will not allow the keys or values to be garbage-collected; items have to be removed manually to free memory.

> For further reference, see [MDN docs on WeakMaps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap). Compare the *Description* section with that of a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: So, if an object pointed to by a weak link has been deleted, then we lose access to the key-value pair (the key is a link to the object that was deleted), but this pair remains in WeakMap? Or I still don't  understand this?

Comment: Usually when you add a key-value pair to a WeakMap, the key is an object. It does not make much sense to use a scalar value to do so. However, when the object you used as a key becomes inaccessible from all other parts of your code (it is garbage-collected or -collectible) then both the key and the value are removed and GC-ed from the WeakMap, hence the “Weak”. At this point you usually don’t care anymore because you no longer have the key around to actually get the value out of the WeakMap.